# Mousemove Slider on Window Resize

Tags: jquery

I use a well-functioning full size Mouse Move Slider (https://jsfiddle.net/nLwb72d0/) (Original by Ryan Bracket: http://jsfiddle.net/RyanBrackett/FSsC9/).
As soon as I reduce the size of the browser window, the sizes of the containers change which makes the mousemove no longer correct.

I've already tried calling the same function on window resize. This leads to the fact that the slider does not stop to jerk.

I also tried to update the variables on window resize. Unfortunately, this was unsuccessful.

```js
$(function () {

    var $bl = $(".item-photo"),
        $th = $(".item-photo-wrapper"),
        blW = $bl.outerWidth(),
        blSW = $bl[0].scrollWidth,
        wDiff = (blSW / blW) - 1, // widths difference ratio
        mPadd = 20, // Mousemove Padding
        damp = 20, // Mousemove response softness
        mX = 20, // Real mouse position
        mX2 = 0, // Modified mouse position
        posX = 0,
        mmAA = blW - (mPadd * 2), // The mousemove available area
        mmAAr = (blW / mmAA); // get available mousemove fidderence ratio

        $(window).on('resize', function(){
            blW = $bl.outerWidth(),
          blSW = $bl[0].scrollWidth,        
            mmAA = blW - (mPadd * 2), // The mousemove available area
            mmAAr = (blW / mmAA); //        
        });



    $bl.mousemove(function (e) {
        mX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        mX2 = Math.min(Math.max(0, mX - mPadd), mmAA) * mmAAr;
    });

    setInterval(function () {
        posX += (mX2 - posX) / damp;
        $th.css({
            marginLeft: -posX * wDiff
        });
    }, 10);
});
```

Comment: Hi! Your jsfiddle doesn't seem to exhibit the problem you're describing. I don't really understand what you mean by "no longer correct" but I'm seeing no change in behavior based on resizing.

Comment: Hey Andrew, 
I'm sorry for the ambiguous question.I changed the description.
When changing the window width The Mouse Move Slider does not work across the entire width, because the elements are shifted. They still have the init values.

Comment: Thanks! No worries, I'll take a look now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're forgetting to recalculate wDiff on window resize. I'd recommend you refactor a little bit so that you don't have to write out the calculations twice in your code. For example, make a function to handle the calculations, then just call it whenever you need to update them, rather than writing them out for both initialization and resize.

What I mean by that is like so:

```js
var recalcSlider = function () {
    blW = $bl.outerWidth();
    blSW = $bl[0].scrollWidth;
    wDiff = (blSW / blW) - 1; // widths difference ratio
    mmAA = blW - (mPadd * 2); // The mousemove available area
    mmAAr = (blW / mmAA);
}

$(window).on('resize', recalcSlider); // calls it on resize
recalcSlider(); // calls it upon initialization
```

...and then you can just initialize your variables at 0 from there.

Comment: Perfect! That's the solution! Thank you so much!!